# How to inset and shear polygons evenly?

Tags: modeling, transforms, workflow, faces, extrude

I have sheared several parts of the mesh on the edge and trying to inset them evenly.

I have tried 2 methods (and also reset all transformations just in case it was a scale issue). But both of them I'm getting uneven results as seen in the examples.

If I use Boolean operation it will make a mess on the object, so I'd like to keep it with clean topology, so whats the correct method to getting the result?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest workaround is to flip the order.

1. Inset/extrude first, so the geometry is even (check *Offset even*)
2. Shear the resulting geometry in any direction
3. Done

[image]

Comment: Hi, J, Beat me to it... me  with I, inset, adjusted:  Depth -xxx, Thickness 0-> xxx.

Comment: Thansk Jachym worked perfect! 

Regards!